# Not able to see file uploaded and save by Jmeter in my web application

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded file upload script in Jmeter for 100 users
script run successfully but files were not uploaded on target server.

In my opinion, ideally uploaded files should visible on targeted 
application.[image]

Please Help !

Comment: Your "Path" seems contains dynamic components, which should be correct for request to succeed. I recommend figuring out what they are and adjusting them. For example `LR_UPLOADER_TS` sounds like it's a "transaction ID", so you may need to retrieve it form previous request, or provide a unique value, etc.

Comment: Can you show your jmeter.log ?

Comment: Actually the real problem is when I am trying to Save the uploaded file.in normal mode file got saved successfully but when I am trying to save file in while recording it is not got saved and failed with FileNotFoundException.

Comment: log file is too big ....please direct me how to share ...but the root in the problem while saving the uploaded file it is not got saved while recording(using proxy server)

Comment: I have solve the problem of not saving the uploaded file by changing the file location to the bin dir but when I run recorded script by uploading other document in HTTP request that file is not getting uploaded in my application